# Is it possible to get a NSTimeZone instance from CLLocation (or CLLocationCoordinates2D)?

Tags: objective-c, timezone, core-location, cllocation

I was doing a lot of research around this and it's hard for me to think that it is not possible to get an instance of `NSTimeZone` for a given `CLLocation` instance (or coordinates) using built-in iOS libraries.

Around the web I saw solutions using a third party rest service or using APTimezones, anyone knows how to do it with apple's frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

CLLocation does not contain a timezone.  There's no reason for that.  It does have an NSDate that specified the date/time the point was recorded, but NSDate's are always UTC time.  You only need a timezone when displaying time in local time.

Comment: I get that, and that's not my question. It should be a way to get the timezone that a given location belongs to. Do you think my question is not clear? if so, I can update the post.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to know the timezone of the time that the CLLocation was collected.  Now I realize you're asking how to get the timezone of a point on the earth based on political boundaries and current laws (for DST).

Comment: Ugh [CLLocation description] prints time zone